# Dapper Mapping List of Results

Tags: c#, sql, orm, dapper

My stored procedure returns back a list of Users along with organisation details from relational table.

I have used dapper to execute the stored procedure in my C# Web API application.

I am new to dapper. How do I map the results returned by stored procedure to my model?

### Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllUsersByOrganisation]
    @OrganisationId int = 0

AS
    SELECT * from dbo.Users u
    inner join dbo.Organisations org on u.OrganisationId = org.Id
    Where u.OrganisationId = @OrganisationId
```

### Execute Method

```
public List<User> GetUseryOrganisation(int organisationId)
{
    var users = DataContextFactory.GetConnectionString(_settings)
        .Execute("dbo.GetAllUsersByOrganisation", new {OrgantisationId = organisationId},
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    // Map to return List of User
}
```

### Models

```
 public class User
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public Organisation Organisation { get; set; }
    }

    public class Organisation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `Query` overload which expects two types in the returned record set (user data and organization data), and then assigns organization data to user entity:

```
var users = DataContextFactory.GetConnectionString(_settings)
    .Query<User, Organisation, User>(
         "dbo.GetAllUsersByOrganisation",
         (u,o) => { u.Organisation = o; return u; }, // map function
         new {OrgantisationId = organisationId},
         commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

return users.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you explain why there are two user object in the Query bracket please?

Comment: @user4453701 first two generic arguments is a data in result set - you have User data and Organization data in each row. Last argument is a type of result. In this case it matches first argument, because you want to return user with organization, but you could use some third type for return value, e.g. ExtendedUser and construct it from User and Organization which you have after processing raw